# Ionic 2 Push Notification when new data on server

Tags: cordova, plugins, push-notification, ionic2

I am writing an Ionic2 Application. I want to send a new notification when there is a new event added into a database I monitor via a public API.

I am currently using this plugin: https://github.com/taivo/parse-push-plugin and Back4App to manage Push Notifications.

I can receive push notifications that I send through the dashboard of Back4App, but I can't figure out how to send push notifications when there is an event added to the database.

How can I run a script that checks if there is a change in the database and sends a notification when there is a database?

Is this possible without running your own server?

Answer (score 0):

For what I could understand from your needs, my suggestion would be to use Cloud Code functions as for example a *beforeSave* that would perform an action right *before* you save any modifications done in your database.

You'll find info on beforeSave method within [Parse's Documentation](http://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/)

Also, you may give it a shot by using Back4App's Background Jobs, that would need to be configured in order to run in an specific time interval (There are limitations regarding the number of jobs that can run simultaneously) and check if anything was changed within the database.

Searching through the site, you may find Background Jobs examples for [iOS](https://docs.back4app.com/docs/ios/background-jobs/) and [Android](https://docs.back4app.com/docs/android/background-job/)

Hope it helps!